# How do I add selected to this code

Tags: php, mysql, input, html-select

```
This code works.
<!doctype html>
<body>
<form  method="post"  >
<?php

$conn = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'myDB');

if ($conn->connect_error){
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql='SELECT DISTINCT counselor_name FROM counselors';
$result = $conn->query($sql);

?>

<select name="name" >
<?php
while ($row =  mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
echo '<option value="'.$row['counselor_name'].'">'.$row['counselor_name'] . '</option>';
}
?>
</select>
<input type="submit" value="GO!"  name="go"/>
</form>
</body>
```

For the life of me, I can not figure out how to incorporate the select function into the option string to select a value.
IE: If I were to set $filter = "John". I would like "John" to be selected.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in one line (your existing echo line) with a ternary operator but in the interest of legibility, this is what you want:

```
if ($row['counselor_name'] === $filter)
{
  echo '<option value="'.$row['counselor_name'].'" selected="selected">'.$row['counselor_name'] . '</option>';
}
else
{
  echo '<option value="'.$row['counselor_name'].'">'.$row['counselor_name'] . '</option>';
}
```

Comment: Thank You...The simplicity of the solution is daunting :-)